# Rebuild index on InnoDB

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, innodb

I have Large table with 2 million rows and 50 columns.
When iam updating/inserting large amount of data  iam dropping all indexes and rebuild them again using 2 queries.  this works fine

But iam thinking to use another query for that
example :

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name]  ENGINE = InnoDB
```

as i read from the mysql guide here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimize-table.html

> InnoDB Details
>
> For InnoDB tables, OPTIMIZE TABLE is mapped to ALTER TABLE ... FORCE,
>   **which rebuilds the table to update inde**x statistics and free unused
>   space in the clustered index. This is displayed in the output of
>   OPTIMIZE TABLE when you run it on an InnoDB table

Also i think optimize will rebuild the index?

```
 OPTIMIZE TABLE [table_name]
```

what do you recommend,  my table have more then 2 million rows and 50 columns

Comment: Can you please restructure your question to ask a specific technical question as opposed to a recommendation?

Comment: I doubt it is even necessary to drop and rebuild the indexes, unless you have too many of them. Do you have some concrete evidence to the contrary?

Answer (score 6):

Have you been doing `SHOW TABLE STATUS` before and after your drop+rebuild?  Does Index_length change much?  Probably not by even a factor of two.

I almost never recommend rebuilding anything in InnoDB.  It's not worth it.  A glaring exception has to do with with `FULLTEXT` indexes.

Yes the dummy `ALTER` will rebuild the indexes.  So will `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.  Both will "defragment" (to some extent) the secondary index BTrees and the main BTree (which contains the data and `PRIMARY KEY`).

The statistics can be *much* more cheaply updated using just `ANALYZE TABLE`.  Even that is not often needed.  5.6 has a much better way of maintaining the stats.

If you are not already using `innodb_file_per_table=ON`, I suggest you set that (`SET GLOBAL ...`) and do `ALTER TABLE tbl ENGINE=InnoDB;` one last time.

**Online alter**

To change `ft_*`, you need to rebuild the index.  This implies an `ALTER` (or `OPTIMIZE`, which is implemented as `ALTER`).  Newer versions of MySQL have `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` which makes `ALTER` have little or no impact on the running system.  But, there are limitations.  Check the manual.

An alternative to a non-INPLACE `ALTER` is `pt-query-digest` or `gh-ost`.  See if either of them will work for your case.

Short of "rebuilding the table", you can `DROP INDEX ...` and `ADD INDEX ...`.  Again, I don't know if these work for FT indexes "inplace".  Anyway, you would lose the use of that index during the process.

Comment: I have changed `innodb_ft_min_token_size` and need to rebuild the fulltext indexes. I think I might need to `optimize table...`. And I have to do it right now...I wish I had some time waiting for your answer

Comment: The `OPTIMIZE` won't do anything more useful than rebuilding the indexes.  (I noted `FULLTEXT` as an exception.)

Comment: While doing `optimize table...`, the tabled is locked so I had to interrupt the query.. it has about 2,000,000 rows.. Could you give any advice?

Comment: If you change ft..., you have to rebuild the index.  Read the manual on `ALTER` to see if this is one of the "inplace" cases.  (I doubt if it is.)

Comment: I added a discussion of online alter options.